# Write output of base64 encode on a file to the same file?

Tags: bash, base64, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04), I have a file, `out.txt` with the phrase `password` that I am encoding using `base64`:

```
$ echo password > out.txt
$ base64 out.txt
$ # returns cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

I wanted to ask if there was some way to write the output of the `base64` command back into its original file `out.txt`. When I try to do so currently (`base64 out.txt > out.txt`), I end up with a blank file. Piping the command's output into another file (`base64 out.txt > oot.txt`) works fine, but I'd prefer if I kept everything to the same file.

Trying to achieve this for the purpose of scripting a shell file with an sshpass command (yes, I know about keyless authentication and whatnot but unfortunately I don't have the ability to configure this on the server I'm connecting to) and would obviously rather not have the password in plaintext in my command history.

Comment: @TedLyngmo This will cause an infinite loop when the size of the file is larger than base64's buffer

Comment: This is probably the easiest: `echo "$(base64 out.txt)" >out.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus that worked well enough for this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge), which (unlike simple pipe) buffers the entire input first before writing it to the given file.

```
base64 out.txt | sponge out.txt
```